# Working with yaml literal-blocks in vim?

Tags: filetype-yaml

I'm trying to work with indenting yaml in vim, and I'm trying to convert it to JSON.

Say I have a file like this:

```
---
  foo: bar
  baz:
    - qux
    - quxx
  corge: null
  grault: 1
  garply: true
  waldo: "false"
  fred: undefined
  literal_block: |
   blah wee  `bib` 
   blah
  # Multiple-line strings can be written either as a 'literal block' (using |),
  # or a 'folded block' (using '>').
  test: blah
```

The literal block part (as well as the indentation overall) are giving me a hard time.

When typing a [literal_block](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2795688) I usually start off with all the content un-indented.

```
  literal_block: |
blah wee  `bib` 
blah
```

Then what I was hoping to do was to indent 3 spaces when I press either the tab key or by pressing >> to indent like this:

```
  literal_block: |
   blah wee  `bib` 
   blah
```

And that should result in an output from the [yaml-to-json parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) of something like this:

```
{
  "waldo": "false", 
  "baz": [
    "qux", 
    "quxx"
  ], 
  "fred": "undefined", 
  "corge": null, 
  "literal_block": "blah wee  `bib` \nblah\n", 
  "grault": 1, 
  "test": "blah", 
  "garply": true, 
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

However, that's not what happens when I press those keys, instead I get

```
  literal_block: |
        blah wee  `bib` 
        blah
```

...and a parser error.

I've even installed the `vim-ansible-yaml plugin` as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27427876/18149).

Should I try a different plugin for my indents?  It seems like literal-block indents have 3 spaces beyond the parent, and everything else gets 2 spaces.

Comment: If I run `:set filetype=ansible`, I find that the indenting works better, but...when I'm doing literal_blocks I still have to add another space on every single line in the literal block.

Comment: Not to say that I can't select all that text and do this: `'<,'>s/^.*$/ \0/g`, but it does seem like whatever plugin I'm using should handle that when working with yaml.